# Use of helmetjs when we can directly set set HTTP related header

Tags: node.js, express, security, helmet.js

I come across helmetjs in Production Best Practices: Security Express doc [here](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html)
 curious to know how it is different than setting headers directly. Also visited helmetjs documentation, I found only how to use it, I want to know how it works and how it is a secure way of setting HTTP related headers (i.e frameguard). 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helmet makes setting the headers easier. It puts them all in one place, gives them an API, does some validation, and [documents everything](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/).

However, it's not much more than that. If you know how to set the headers yourself and understand their ins and outs, Helmet isn't going to be too useful.

(I'm Helmet's maintainer, for what it's worth!)

Comment: All in one place, some validation makes sense. I am not sure whether this is the right platform to ask for elaborated or not. wanted to know how it makes the difference between following. app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('X-Frame-Options' , 'ALLOW-FROM https://example.com');
  next();
});


app.use(helmet({
  frameguard: {
    action: 'ALLOW-FROM https://example.com'
  }
})). I did not found  details on git page or on official page. references will be appreciated.

Comment: Not much difference. I think [the source code](https://github.com/helmetjs/frameguard/blob/8a66af9c73514293eb7356b1620acc75368ecb40/index.js) is probably the best place to understand what Helmet does in addition to that. Basically, it just does validation and supports non-Express environments.